# 503 Service Unavailable for google endpoints

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, objectify

I am using endpoints to try and create a patient entity for my web application. i keep getting the following error code when i try to run the API.

```
    503 Service Unavailable

- Show headers -

    {
     "error": {
      "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "backendError",
    "message": "java.lang.IllegalStateException: You have not started an Objectify context. You are probably missing the ObjectifyFilter. If you are not running in the context of an http request, see the ObjectifyService.run() method."
   }
  ],
  "code": 503,
  "message": "java.lang.IllegalStateException: You have not started an Objectify context. You are probably missing the ObjectifyFilter. If you are not running in the context of an http request, see the ObjectifyService.run() method."
 }
}
```

I know this is something to do with the static ofy file and i am not exactly sure how to add the filter to it. 
Here is the code for my static objectify file.

```
import com.googlecode.objectify.Objectify;
import com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyService;


public class OfyService 
{
    public static Objectify ofy() 
    {
        return ObjectifyService.ofy();
    }
}
```

i then call the ofy file by using this method in the API class

```
ofy().save().entity(patient).now();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code to your `web.xml`

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>ObjectifyFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>ObjectifyFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Thanks very much @tomrozb. It now says something about registering my class that i take the information from, is there an objectify register method i need to paste into the web.xml?

Comment: never mind, i added the correct statement to the static method. for anyone else having these problems, i had to enter this code to the ofyService class `static{
  ObjectifyService.register(Patient.class);
 }`